# How change label.text value from a worker thread in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

i upload a file using ftp, and to not get my GUI stuck i use a thread which do the Job.

I want to display in a label control text value the remaining bytes.

how can do this. (i use VS.NET 2005, Web application)

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with plain asp.net. The reason is that you cannot mix server and client code this way. Use AJAX control toolkit to do things like this.

Do you know how asp.net works? At first whole page is prepared on server and then it is sent as html to client web browser. Then you cannot change anything - it is not a program, just html page. When you want to do changes in labels you need to go back to server and download whole pages again.

AJAX allows you to update pages without sending whole content. You can also manually do some stuff in JavaScript, but it will be probably much easier for you to use AJAX than to learn JavaScript. (Especially when you actually hardly understand client-server principles.)